# OKI-B2540 printer doesn't print?

Tags: printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OKI B2540 - still doesn't print?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80847/oki-b2540-still-doesnt-print)

There is a driver for the OKI-B2520, and it is automatically selected when the printer is connected. From looking at various websites, it seems like the B2500, B2520, and B2540 all work perfectly fine with the OKI-B2520 driver, so I let it install that. Everything went smoothly, the printer shows up as available, and I can queue jobs without any problems, and they disappear after a few seconds.

However, nothing actually comes out. There is no error message on the printer display, or from Ubuntu.

This is the output from the CUPS error log: http://pastebin.com/S6ifZAup

So my question is: What is wrong??