# OKI B2540 - still doesn't print?

Tags: printing

I've read the item "OKI B2540 printer doesn't print", here and elsewhere, but I still don't know what to do, or if it is even possible!

Comment: have you tried with the PPD from openprinting?  http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Oki/Oki-B2540_MFP

Answer (score 1):

Enabling the error log for cups might show something useful: Press Alt+F2 and type

```
gksudo gedit /etc/cups/cupsd.conf
```

Then find the line that says`LogLevel warn` and change it to `LogLevel debug`. After rebooting, there should be a file called "error.log" in /var/log/cups/. Make note of its last line, then try to print something. Does something new appear in the log?

Comment: This is the output: http://pastebin.com/S6ifZAup

Comment: The output seems rather sane with the exception of repeating itself a lot. Did all that come out of just one print attempt?
Also, knowing the following would help:
Ubuntu distribution/variant/release/everything
The exact name of your driver (run system-config-printer, select printer, properties, look for "Make and model"; mine says "Canon BJC-1000 Foomatic/bjc250gs")